# Why am I losing the grouping column header in renderDT when renaming the other columns in the table?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

When running the below MWE code exactly as drafted, you'll see how in the bottom table titled "Sum the data table columns:", the left-most column header, the grouping key, changes as the user selects how to group the data by (by either Period_1 or by Period_2).

But I'd like to change the names of the remaining column headers, "ColA" and "ColB", to "Col A" and "Col B" for example. (This is because in the fuller App this example is deployed I'm trying to use more industry-standard descriptions for the columns and need the white spaces --- bear with me here). To change these 2 column headers, I use the `colnames = (...)` function under `renderDT(...)` in the `server` section. Note how this line is commented-out below. Now uncomment it, run the code, and see how the name for the left-most column, the grouping key, is dropped. I'd like to retain the grouping column header name ("Period_1" or "Period_2" depending on user input).

Any ideas how to retain it?

Here's the MWE code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)


ui <-
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 8,
          h3("Data table:"),
          tableOutput("data"),
          h3("Sum the data table columns:"),
          radioButtons(
            inputId = "grouping",
            label = NULL,
            choiceNames = c("By period 1", "By period 2"),
            choiceValues = c("Period_1", "Period_2"),
            selected = "Period_1",
            inline = TRUE
          ),
          DT::dataTableOutput("sums")
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Period_1 = c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03"),
      Period_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2),
      ColA = c(1000.01, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
      ColB = c(15.06, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65)
    )
  })
  
  summed_data <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      group_by(!!sym(input$grouping)) %>%
      select("ColA","ColB") %>%
      summarise(across(everything(), sum))
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data())

  output$sums <- renderDT({
    summed_data() %>% 
      datatable(
        rownames = FALSE,
        # colnames = c("Col A","Col B")
        )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your `colnames` parameter is of length two.  Your summary table has three columns.  That's why one of your column headers is blank.  To make the column headers change as your grouping variable changes, make them reactive:  `colNames <- reactive({c(stringr::str_replace(input$grouping, fixed("_"), " "), "Col A", "Col B") })` and then `colnames=colNames()`.

Comment: Works perfectly. I don't think I would have ever solved that one on my own. I didn't know reactivity could reach that far deeply. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of Limey's solution (only the `server` section is shown below, everything else remains as shown in OP):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Period_1 = c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03"),
      Period_2 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2),
      ColA = c(1000.01, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
      ColB = c(15.06, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65)
    )
  })
  
  # add the below to leave grouping column header untouched:
  colNames <- reactive({c(input$grouping, "Col A", "Col B") })
  
  # add the below to replace the "_" in the grouping column header with a blank space:
  # colNames <- reactive({c(stringr::str_replace(input$grouping, fixed("_"), " "), "Col A", "Col B") })
  
  summed_data <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      group_by(!!sym(input$grouping)) %>%
      select("ColA","ColB") %>%
      summarise(across(everything(), sum))
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data())

  output$sums <- renderDT({
    summed_data() %>% 
      datatable(
        rownames = FALSE,
        colnames=colNames() # < add colNames()
        )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```